# CakePHP: recursive column names

Tags: php, cakephp, model

I am trying to develop a CakePHP application using several models and defining relations within those models.

Now, I need to retrieve a model's fieldset (i.e., column names) to create a nice form. I am familiar with getColumnTypes and schema, but I need to get fields recursively, so that I can feed the output to Backbone.js.

For example, suppose I have a Customer model with a field 'name', and a hasOne relationship to an Address mode, with a field 'street', I need to somehow obtain a structure like the one below.

```
{
  "name",
  "Address": {
    "subschema": {"street"}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define the `hasOne` relationship from Address to subschema and so on, and when querying the data use [recursive keyword](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive)

Comment: Thank you. The relationships are defined. Please note I am interested in getting the field tiles, not the values themselves. I will clarify this in the question.